# Problem with green and blue RGB diodes

Tags: power-supply, diodes, automotive, rgb

I have a setup of 6 RGB diodes in parrallel, each diode has seperate resistors for each color.

My problem is, when i connect the diodes  on a 12v supply, all leds and every color works, but when i connect the diodes on my speakers, green and blue dont work on 1 diode, red works on all.

What could posibbly cause this problem? If leds work normaly if connected to 12V, but 1 doesnt work if connected to speaker.

Comment: Why on earth are you connecting LEDs to speakers?

Comment: Thats besides the point but yeah.. i want them to "puls" by the beat. And yeah i know thats not how you do it but ok...

Comment: Yeah that's not going to work at all. You need some proper driver circuitry to do that.

Comment: @Polynomial Well the funny thing is. The speakers had blue leds on before, but wanted to upgrade. I updated 2 speakers with the same diodes, one set of rgb diodes work fine even on music. The other doesnt, only if i hook it directly to 12V it does.. Its still waird how just 1 diode doesnt work..

Comment: Use the schematic editor that comes with this site and add two schematics: (1) The 12 V schematic; and, (2) your speaker schematic. I think that if you put some work into your question here, that you will get some work back in the form of a useful answer.

Comment: @jonk No offense but what would a schematic change? They r bouth the same just that one is connected to 12V supply, one is connected to speakers + and -. The item in use is the same.

Comment: It would be the considerate thing to do as it would require less guessing on our part, fewer questions, etc. It's up to you, though. You do what you want.

Comment: unfortunly i do not know where to find or how to do a schemathic. But i fixed the problem by changing the led, now it works.

Comment: There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It's easy to use. You need to supply part numbers and links to the datasheets for the LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

Your RED are probably not working at full current and BG may be backwards damaged or just not enough audio power, but have 50% higher  voltage threhold.

To get the same brightness, they have to be equally efficient and with 12V into 8 Ohms that is 18 watts of audio power.

If they are not ESD protected or back-front connected inparallel, then worry about reverse V damage>-5V

Comment: This is an interesting answer.
1. Red leds seem to work at full power almost all the time.
Its the first time i hear about backwards damage, it could be a posibility.

2.I tried changing volume to max still one diode didnt work. 5 leds work 1 not, i do not think its a problem with power. But the waird thing is that on 12v all 6 GB work. 

3. How to know if they r ESD protected? How does backfront parrallel look like?

4. I fixed it by changing the one diode and now all 6 work on audio. But im interested to know about ESD and reverse V dmg

Comment: MOST LEDs are not ESD protected unless there are two Leds , 1 for each polarity.  I only buy ESD protected types when avail.  Others can add a shunt diode in reverse across each Light Emitting Diode.  ( What/where was that one diode?)